What is the Best UI/UX design for a Pricing Table With Moderate Data
I am designing a website for knife sharpening and in one section I want to display the different pricing rates per quantity.
This is what I have so far but I want to improve and I'm not quite sure how.

Do you guys have any suggestions on websites that have done something similar or should I abandon this way of displaying data? My end goal is for a user to quickly understand how much it costs to sharpen the blade they have.


Remove all repeated elements with a clarification outside the table
Magnify all important data
Reduce the price info to just the figure
Change the "results" alignment to center


